# QGIS 3D Animations sequential photos to video

Tags: qgis, 3d, animation, 3d-map

The 3D save animation function output in QGIS (3.16) is a set of sequential photos.

How do I transform those images to video?

I tried converting to GIF but the file was too heavy.

Answer (score 2):

[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) is probably the right tool for that.
You will be able to convert png images to MP4 movie by using that kind of command line :

`ffmpeg -r 3 -i frame%03d.png -vcodec libx264 -vf "scale=1200:-2" output-file.mp4`

See the documentation : https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

And Alasdair Rae has just written a blog post on how to use ffmpeg : http://www.statsmapsnpix.com/2021/12/map-animations-with-ffmpeg.html

Comment: I have no familiarity with FFMPEG. Do you have any recommended tutorial?

Comment: See the wiki : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki and see also : https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial