# Exporting animation video or gif with qgisthree2js plug-in in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, 3d, 3d-model

I created a 3D scene with the qgisthree2js plug-in in QGIS and prepared an animation with 18 frames. I'd like to export it as a gif or video, but there are only png and glTF options. I tried screen-recording, but the quality drops dramatically as well. How can I export my 18-frame animation as a video file?
[image]

Comment: FFMPEG? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418959/276

Comment: Yep, just export as png and use an external tool like ffmpeg to convert to video or GIMP to convert to gif.